# Copy Paste Macro

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

I have a macro that searches the columns for a specific value and if true, copies ALL of the rows containing that value to a different worksheet. However, it does not seem to work as it only copies the very last row, rather than all of the rows with the specific value.

Basically, I input data into column B, and column C returns a result via `VLOOKUP`, and column D states TRUE/FALSE. When a value returns TRUE in column D, I want it to copy the entire row and paste it into another sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim C As Range
    Dim Test As Worksheet
    Dim Pastesheet As Worksheet

    'Find the last row with data in column C
    LR = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    'look at every cell in D2 onwards
    For Each C In Range("D2:D" & LR)
        If C.Value = True Then

            'Copy code
            Set Test = Worksheets("Test Sheet")  ' Copy From this sheet
            Set Pastesheet = Worksheets("Inventory")  ' to this sheet

            C.EntireRow.Copy  ' copy the row from column D that meets that requirements
            Pastesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats        
        End If    
    Next C
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably want to change `LR = ActiveSheet.Cells()` to have the actual sheet you're counting the cells on. Also, add the worksheet you want the `C` range to be on. Right now, with just `Range("D2:D" & LR)` it's going to use the ActiveSheet.

Comment: just get the last row in your PasteSheet before the loop, and define a counter and inside your loop add counter=counter+1 and use the counter as the row that you will paste the entire row. The good thing about this is you will also count how many matches you had

Comment: Thank you guys, any chance you can type exactly where to place those suggestions? I am very new to writing macros. That would be greatly appreciated.